# Java - Export and build eclipse project from target folder

Tags: java, eclipse

How can I export files to eclipse project from the target folder?
I lost my project files. All I have is a target folder with binary .class files and static files in html.
Can you somehow build a project out of it?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You can't go back to the original source files from just class files. You could decompile them which means you get code stripped of all names and comments except for method/fieldnames, code is mangled and worse, and probably broken. If you must - [Here are some decompilers](http://www.javadecompilers.com). Not sure if that site truly works (sites that only load over plain jane http are rather suspicious), but even if not, just search the web for any of the decompilers named there and run it on those class files.

As I said, the end result will look horrible, but it's the best you can do.